# Mobile Safari - Article, text and images blurry on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, html, mobile-safari

So, my site looks blurry on Mobile Safari. I have an iPhone 3GS, and whenever I go to one of my articles in my site... oh yes, blurriness...

Is it maybe too big for my old iPhone 3GS, in addition to the resources-hungry iOS5?

[image: Blurry text on Mobile Safari]

If anyone with an iPod or iPhone could test it, it would be much appreciated. I'd like to know if anyone else have this issue.

The article from the screenshot is [at this link](http://artpulse.me/articles/Senses/)

And most importantly... Anyone know why?

There is no CSS transformation or perspective of any kind being applied to neither the **article** tag nor it's parents.

Thanks!

Comment: Image is nice and sharp on my iPhone 4, iOS 4, and on my iPad 2, iOS 5.

Comment: That is very weird, clear your cache? It looks fine to me. http://i.imgur.com/FASvB.jpg, note this is a screenshot from my iPhone 4, the free imgur app doesn't let you upload a full image, makes you crop it down :-\

Comment: @ChrisWagner good tip. It did make my Mobile Safari faster. I entered the address again and looked fine, until I began to zoom in and rotate the device. Then blurriness again. I'm guessing it's my outdated iPhone =/ could it be?

Comment: You all are using modern iDevices!! hah xD - I want an iPhone 3G (2nd gen) user to test it now...

Comment: iPhone 3G here .. looks good .. no problems ..

Comment: Well then... I guess it's not a coding issue then, just my iPhone... then this topic is closed..... how do I close this xD...

Comment: Sorry to bump this, but I've experienced this on a 3gs and 4 running 4.2.1.  In both cases though, it was when -webkit-transform:translate3d was being applied via javascript BEFORE initial rendering.  I had to do a setTimeout after the onload event to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if your device is nearly out of memory and then has to allocate a huge amount e.g. for sites that have some big javascripts running and loading data over ajax.
Try closing all running apps (taskmanager -> double click the home button) and load again.

Comment: +1. I also had to close most of my Safari tabs too, but this resolved a similar issue for me.

Comment: I assume that this is an issue that occurs from time to time with way newer OS versions than the originally installed on a device. I for example experienced it with iOS 5 on my iPad 1. I'm sure iOS 5 uses a lot more memory than iOS 3 did back then and the older devices just don't have very much RAM...

Answer (score 0):

Blurry on my iOS 5.0.1 3GS. Seen it on a couple of other sites too

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess there is not much to do but wait for Apple to handle it better =P